# Is there a Github clone in PHP that I can run on my own server?

Tags: git, version-control, github

I know there are plenty of ways to run git on my server, but I quite like the functionality of git with repo browsing - the fact that i can look at previous versions in the web interface.

Now was I able to, I'd use github, but the problem is our source control rules are very strict and we aren't allowed to put files on other servers, even if they are encrypted.

Is there a script that allows us to run a github like interface, or rather one that allows me to browse the revision history of the git project through a web interface?

I'm running a LAMP server, but would consider alternate languages like python, perl etc should nothing in php be available.

interested in both paid and open source softwares

Comment: Not 100% duplicate, but many relevant answers: [Is there a commercial grade Git server product](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3299222/). Also worth looking at: [white-label collaborative open-source development (e.g. github/sourceforge/google-code in a box) ?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2733691/).

Comment: `closed as not constructive` and 77+1 upvotes...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The webapp behind [Gitorious](http://gitorious.org/) is open-source. You can have an interface exactly like it from your web server. It doesn't have all the Github bells and whistles but it has source browsing, revision history, commits, etc.

It's rails, which might not be optimal for you, but it's also free :-)

Comment: http://gitorious.org/gitorious/pages/Installation

Answer (score 23):

Git itself comes with [Gitweb](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gitweb), which is a basic browser interface to a Git repository. It allows browsing arbitrary versions of the tree.

You can see Gitweb in action at http://git.kernel.org

Comment: And here are some instructions to install gitweb: http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/05/06/8-ways-to-share-your-git-repository/. Those are the ones I used anyway.

Answer (score 17):

I know this is a late response, but there is a fabulous PHP application call gitlist. http://gitlist.org/

It works great and looks beautiful.

Comment: also found this http://gitlab.org/ not PHP but Rails

Answer (score 10):

If you are willing to pay you can get your own installation of Github. It's called [Github Enterprise](http://enterprise.github.com/) and it charges on a per user basis (roughly $5000/year for every 20-seat license).  They provide you with a VM and you supply the infrastructure to run it on.