# Can i use git version control application without github?

Tags: git, version-control, open-source, github

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a commercial grade Git server product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299222/is-there-a-commercial-grade-git-server-product)
>   [Is there a Github clone that I can run on my own server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988238/is-there-a-github-clone-that-i-can-run-on-my-own-server)

Can i use Git without GitHub's service? What i mean is, i am only the person working on the project and don't want to push the project into the Git space. What do you think? Will this be a right decision? Or is there any lite github like server application available for internal use? Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Marked as duplicate, yet neither of the linked-to "duplicate" questions actually answers this question. The first "duplicate" refers to a commercial-grade Git product (not the focus of this question). The second "duplicate" refers to a GitHub clone (also not the focus of this question).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, git is independent of GitHub. If you push your source to GitHub the with a free account your project will need to be 'public' meaning anyone can read it. Other companies offer free private git repositories (I use `Assembla`). But you can actually use git without any server as well, to maintain local version control.  This is definitely good practice anyway. A server would give you the added advantage of off site backup.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass through http://githowto.com/ , to gain basic GIT skills

Answer (score 1):

I use version control irrespective of whether I share it with the likes of GitHub.

Version control for me means more than just offsite back up.

It means I'm able to experiment with any and all of my ideas (and the subsequent code) without fear of losing anything (at least in terms of stuff on my machine in this scenario) and can always branch or roll back depending on what's needed.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you work in teams, having a github-like functionality is really nice (but not strictly necessary)

[gitorious](http://gitorious.org) is a an open-source github-like (but will a lot less functionality) server application that you can install in-house. github also has this option, but it costs a lot.