# Using Git w/o Github for private single-developer project with Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio

I am doing single developer android project in android studio on my windows PC. The android app is for my own private use. I just want to be able to get back to  stable versions of my code when I screw it up, in ongoing development. I have no desire or need to publish to gitHub repository. Is it possible to use just git on my PC (w/o link to github) within android studio?

Comment: yes you can use git for version control without pushing your code to github.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i use git version control application without github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381864/can-i-use-git-version-control-application-without-github)

Answer (score 1):

Just create a local repository either using command `git init` on the project root or IDEA > VCS > Enable version control (more [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/enabling-version-control.html)). And commit there from now on

Answer (score 0):

Use [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/). It's free to create your own private repository and works the same as Github. You will have to generate a public key for a private repository though. [Here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html) is the documentation on this.

I use Gitlab on all my personal projects and then add Github later on if I want to share to a bigger audience.

You can also host your own server locally, if you need that extra privacy. There's a [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/) to do it easily too