# Does one have to use GitHub to see pull request comments within Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

I am using *GitHub extension for Visual Studio v2.6.1.6227* (dated 12/14/2018) and all the online documentation says that I should be able to see pull requests comments within the IDE but I cannot.

One possibly significant difference in our usage is that we are using an on-site Git repository rather than using GitHub.

**So, does one have to use GitHub to see pull request comments within Visual Studio 2015?**

Comment: Pull request are a GitHub proprietary feature, so if you're using normal Git, they don't even exist.

Comment: That is decidedly not true.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381864/can-i-use-git-version-control-application-without-github

Comment: The linked post don't even mention pull requests, just "Git without GitHub", which is pretty much what I said. I also add that pull request don't exist in Git and are a GitHub feature and not a Git feature.